# How to structure a Research Proposal for an MPhil

Tags: graduate-admissions

I'm in the midst of applying for an MPhil in the UK and the terminology for this application is a bit different than what I'm used to. The course website is asking for a research proposal, and I'm looking for some advice on how to structure this. They're asking that the proposal be between 600-1000 words, that it include a 'rationale', a brief 'historiography', and an indication of sources likely to be used.

What I'm wondering specifically is how to format the "sources likely to be used" section. Am I supposed to do this in full bibliographic format? Or is a simple "Author: Title(Year), Title (Year), Title (Year); Author: Title (Year), Title (Year), etc." good enough. I find putting my sources in full bibliographic format is putting me way over the word count, and making it so that the sources likely to be used is larger than the rationale and the historiography combined.

A second issue is that I'm not sure if I should have a works cited for the proposal itself, for points I've made within. If so, there's so much overlap between it and my "sources likely to be used" that I figure I should just combine them? Everything I've cited in the proposal I'm likely to use in my research.

Lastly, in terms of number of sources, is one supposed to be quite thorough, listing all of the primary and secondary sources they think they might use? Because in full bibliographic format that itself is about 600 words when I do it, if not more. And if not, how does one possibly limit themselves to 2-4, or even 5-10, potential sources for an entire masters thesis.

Any input appreciated!

Comment: What field/topic? Which university? This sounds extremely specific to the university and course; have you tried searching for examples or even getting in touch with students or tutors on that course? Perhaps an admissions tutor could clarify these points, especially regarding the word count.